# Migrate to Spring Security 3.0.5.RELEASE

Tags: spring, security, migrate

Hi I have a problem when I try to migrate from Spring Security 2.0.4 to Spring Security 3.0.5.RELEASE. I got following error:

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class pl.casses.fw.client.info.app.OfficeContextLoader
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/office-mgt-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

My security.xml file is here:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.ico" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.gif" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.jpg" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.css" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.png" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/index.jsp"
        authentication-failure-url="/index.jsp?login_error=1"
        default-target-url="/main.jsp" always-use-default-target="true" />
    <remember-me key="CassesOMRMKey" user-service-ref="userFactory"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userFactory">
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And in pom.xml I have:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to migrate to Security 3.0. Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Try to use the same spring version, so 3.0.5...meanwhile, since you are migrating now, why don't you migrate to the latest spring version directly?

Comment: Read this article of common issues as well: http://www.packtpub.com/article/migration-to-spring-security-3

Comment: did the usage of the same version work for you? So I publish it as an answer for future reference

Comment: @mardavi: unfortunatly simple changing spring version in pom.xml does't resolve the problem. I got many different errors (cause I'm working on quite big project). And which is the latest spring version?

Comment: It is 3.2.0.RELEASE for Spring Framework and 3.1.3.RELEASE for Spring Security. In my experience, this mismatch of version is quite common, but in few days both will be 3.2.0.RELEASE. As in your case, this is not always an issue but I've been told by some colleagues that it is better to keep the same release

Comment: Ok, I found solution. I have to add exclusions in pom.xml to all spring artifacts which are used and which have version below 3.0. I was checking dependency hierarchy and added exclusions in pom.xml file.

Comment: Great! Then it was a version-related issue! I convert the first into a possible answer, adding your extra-step of updating maven dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The solution came out in two steps:

1. use the same Spring Release for both artifacts;
2. update maven dependencies, adding exclusions in pom.xml to all spring artifacts using a version below 3.0 (thanks to @caro2 for pointing that out)